# Jquery Selector Performance Advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a very big single html page. I am performing data manipulation to that page. I am wondering if there is any best way for Jquery selector.
like

```
$("#id").text("ABC");
```

Above statement searches for tags in my HTML page, since my HTML is very big. is there any performance tip for that ?

for ex:

Which one is faster ?

```
$(document).on("click", "#contactsTab", callback);
```

or

```
$("#contactsTab").on("click", callback);
```

Comment: Searching by "id" value like that is very fast.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: Do you have a specific scenario where the above is causing you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to re-use `$("#id")`, I would store it in a variable and then use that. Otherwise, you're searching through the DOM each time for that element.

```
var $element = $("#id");
$element.text("ABC");
```

Comment: The browser does that, actually. I'm not saying I wouldn't also do it, provided the element is stable, just saying, it probably doesn't make much difference at all.

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know that. I watched a video on Pluralsight and the author suggested doing that, especially in loops, so I always try and store them in variables if I use the selector more than once. Good to know though!

Comment: Particularly in loops, you save at least: 1. jQuery parsing the string (although no surprise it's optimized for that), and 2. A call into the DOM layer. It's not at all useless, and I do it by default and recommend it. And in artificial, repeated tests it's dramatically different. But in real-world terms, it's not as big a thing as you'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Searching by id is the fastest dom search. It might be nominally faster to do:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "ABC";
```

Answer (score 0):

An ID selector should have the most optimal of all jQuery selector performances.
Ideally you should not have more than one element on the page having that id.